# Jquery Target parent node when checkbox unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have this Jquery code, that will remove color  from the text if the checkbox is not checked.  However , there are multiple divs with the checkbox for the same model, when I uncheck one checkbox , all divs with the model class are unchecked/color removed.  how can i alter this to target the parent Nodes of the checkbox only :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      var togClass=$(this).attr('class');
      if($(this).attr('checked')){
     this.parentNode$('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "inline-block");
      }
      else {
         $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "none");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use one class to color the text of the div, so you can alter it easily by adding and removing the given class:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('checked'))
           $(this).parent('div').addClass('colorclass');
        else
            $(this).parent('div').removeClass('colorclass');
    });
```